# Resize canvas to window / user control size

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, svg

Hi I convert SVG image to XAML/canvas. I would like set this canvas as window/user control background.

Something like this:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
Name="svg2383" Width="800" Height="600">

    <---->
    </Canvas>
    </Window>
```

My problem is Canvas is too much big, I would like automatic resize/stretch canvas on window  height/width.

Image on canvas is complicated..http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/something_wall?content=115863

So set Width and Height is not solution, because this canvas consist other canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the canvas within a [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx).  This will allow you to stretch it to fill the window, while designing it at a constant size.

Comment: Ok, but I would like have canvas as background, because I want put some controls on this background. If I use viewbox, in view box I must put canvas and in canvas I must put control as grid with other controls. I think it’s no good.

Comment: @jminarik: Make a separate canvas - use it for your other controls, and put the Viewbox and it in a Grid.  Should work fine.

Comment: This is the only reliable way I found to do it.

Answer (score 3):

How about removing specified width and height

```
<canvas Name="svg2383">
<---->
</canvas>
```

EDIT: Another way is to use a binding as follows:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWin">
   <Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=ActualWidth}"
      Height="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=ActualHeight}">
   <--->
   </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: So set Width and Height is not solution, because this canvas consist other canvas. So canvas has other canvas and he has other canvas, I must set many properties height and width...this is not solution.